# Before pseudo-element no showing even with required properties

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn about using linear-gradients to "fake" animated element borders with "pseudo-element" like "::before". I've been searching information and every topic I saw was with missing "display" or missing "content" declaration. The thing is that I have declared content and display(tried with block, inline-block, inline) properties. Here's my HTML and CSS. It may be a problem with linear-gradient but right now I'm not able to see it.

```
.elem::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 1%, transparent 0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.elem:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
} 
- CSS

<div>
    <h1 class="elem">TEST</h1>
</div>
-HTML
```

PS: I forgot to add that if I add one single letter to the content property, it works as intended but I need it empty.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you need to give the pseudo element a height and width, could you describe what you want the animation to do? Where does it start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its there you have to give it a height and a width

```css
.elem:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.elem:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 class="elem">TEST</h1>
</div>
```